# Mouse scrolling in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, right-click, scroll-wheel

I'm not actually sure whether this is the expected behavior or a bug of some sort.

In the standard terminal in Windows 10 (`cmd.exe`), I can scroll using the mouse scroll wheel only when a subprocess isn't actively running in the terminal.

For example, if I do `ping -t www.google.com`, I can't scroll up or down until I've Ctrl+Ced out of it. This appears to apply to any program running in the terminal (including things like the python shell).

I've only tested the behavior on two different Windows machines, but they both behave the same way. Powershell doesn't have this problem. I'm pretty sure it didn't used to be a problem.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I've always been able to scroll with the mouse in cmd, even when running `ping` like  above

Comment: I agree with phuclv. Although with every output, the scroll jumps back to the end (to be able to write the output there).